# Objective-C: How to programme a consecutive series of events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, screenshot

Objective-C drives me slightly crazy. I know that it is not a language which processes every command after the other, but what if I need to do this?

For instance, my problem is that I would like to:

1. Take a screenshot of my current iPhone screen
2. Before adding this screenshot to my screen, I would like to add another view
3. Then add the screenshot so that the other view is HIDDEN BENEATH
4. Then have an animation which slides the screenshot out of view and reveals what is HIDDEN BENEATH

Right now, the app will take a screenshot of all the views added in the method (completely ignoring my order of the events) and will not HIDE the added view BENEATH my screenshot. Whatever I try to do, everything will always happen at once and this sucks.

This is my code:

```
- (void)takeScreenShot
{
    screenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self screenshot]];
    [screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 480)];

    accessoryView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:accessoryView]; // which is hidden beneath and about to be revealed
    [self.view addSubview:screenShotView];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:screenShotView];

    [self startAnimation];
}

- (void)startAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                         accessoryView.hidden = NO;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                                               delay:0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                          animations:^{
                                              screenShotView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-320, 0);   
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){                                        
                                          }
                          ];    
                     }];
}



- (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the screenshot image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you are creating a screenshot of a view that's already there and like to present it as a complete image?

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Thanks for your question! I'd like to achieve a page-turn effect. So first, I'd like to take a shot of the 'old' or present page and then get rid of that old page and show the page hidden beneath... Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah I see. Alright, is accessoryView already hidden, meaning hidden property set to yes before you add it?

Comment: @Nick Weaver: I guess another way would be to 'fade' out the current view by doing manipulating the view.frame (which should contain everything currently displayed) and animate the frame from 320x480 to 0x480 ... don't know.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: as for your question, no, the hidden property is not set to yes... would that make a difference? and how and where could I set it? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @n.evermind, yes yes that would be much easier. Still it's your requirement. Please answer my question or change your question with the goal in mind, we may come up with a simpler solution then.

Comment: You just do `accessoryView.hidden = YES;` before you add it as it has already been instantiated obviously. Try that first.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Actually, I think it is easier with a screenshot. Basically, I have three elements on the screen: a label, an UITextField and an UITextView. If you 'turn' to a new page, I need to present the new label, UITextField and UITextView. So if I don't work with the screenshot, I would need to define a second set of UITextFields/UITextViews (one presently shown and one hidden). With a screenshot, I can set up the new UITextFields etc. in the background and then simply get rid of the old page. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Nick Weaver: I've just updated the code accordingly. However, accessoryView doesn't appear at all anymore.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: I guess I need to set the hidden to NO again - but when and where?

Comment: Try to set in the animation block. You may move the revealing part to a new method and call it with a slight delay, by using performSelector.

Comment: @Nick: I still have no luck. I updated the code accordingly, but still, the accessory view is still on top of the screenshot. I was wondering if it has perhaps something to do with the way I take the screenshot. Perhaps the screenshot is not taken of everything that appears, but everything which does not appear or is set to hidden... don't know.

Comment: Alright, I'll try something simple with you screenshot code. Will take a few minutes.

Comment: @n.evermind just threw in my 50 cents :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no real answer but comments don't offer enough space.

I just recreated a simple project to see if the order of adding the views does any difference to the screenshot.

I used a view based application template. The nib has two buttons, connected to properties btn1 and btn2. See screenshot 1. The upper button btn1 is connect to an action to start taking the screenshot and adding it below the buttons to see a difference. The second button is hidden initially.

**screenshot 1**

[image]

Here is my code of the viewController. myView is your accessory view, which will be created on viewWillAppear. This view contains a label as you'll see later.

**Header**

```
...

@interface ScreenshotviewsViewController : UIViewController 
{
    UIButton *btn1;
    UIButton *btn2;

    UIView *myView;
}

@property (nonatomic ,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
@property (nonatomic ,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
@property (nonatomic ,retain) UIView *myView;

- (IBAction)doTheThings;

@end
```

I'll skip your screenshot method: nothing changed, works like a charm :). Result in **screenshot 2**

- take screenshot
- show btn2
- add myView as subview
- add screenshot as subview

As you can see, the screenshot does not show the other views. I just added it below the buttons to see the differences.

**Implementation: case 1**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.myView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50)] autorelease];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 40)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [myView addSubview:label];

    label.text = @"fooo";

    [label release];
}

- (IBAction)doTheThings
{
    UIImageView *screenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self screenshot]];
    [screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 230, 320, 480)];

    btn2.hidden = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [self.view addSubview:screenShotView];
    [screenShotView release];
}
```

**screenshot 2**

[image]

case two would be

- show btn2
- add myView as subview
- take screenshot
- add screenshot as subview

  - (IBAction)doTheThings
    {
    btn2.hidden = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    UIImageView *screenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self screenshot]];
    [screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 230, 320, 480)];

    [self.view addSubview:screenShotView];
    [screenShotView release];
    }

**screenshot 3**

[image]

As you can see the order is recognized. I've left out the animation though. Remove the animation and see if works then. Else try this in a seperate project like I did and see if it works in isolation. If yes we'll have to dig down into you app more.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I'll do as you suggest and try this in a separate project. Will let you know when I'm done. Thanks so much again.

Comment: I tried this and it works. You were actually right, there is a mistake in my other app and I only realised that there is one by creating this other project. THanks so much for your help. I will accept this as the right answer, because I think it is indeed the answer to the question as I posed it. Thank you!!

Comment: I just posted a follow up question in which you can see the result at work: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764263/how-to-hide-the-frame-of-an-uiimage-gradually)