# How to decrease the width of a frame of an UIImage gradually without distorting it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I think this is a very basic question, but I am struggling with this one.

I have a screenshot (an UIImage) which I put into an UIView (called screenShotView in my sample below). I want to get rid of this screenShotView by gradually revealing what is behind this screenShotView. Right now my screenShotView SQUEEZES to the left, but I would like its FRAME to become less and less until the screenShotView is no longer seen (without Squeezing).

This is my code. If I did the same transformation with an UITextView (instead of an UIImage) it would work exactly how I would like it to behave (without transformation).

Perhaps I don't get the concept of framing UIImages?

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10];

    [screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 480)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

---

And this is how it looks like in the middle of the animation:

[image]

And this is how I would like it to look like in the middle of the animation:
[image]

---

This is the code updated to Codo's suggestions (see below), with the result that I have no animation anymore. The blue screen simply pops up once the button is pressed. I guess that I am doing something wrong with adding the subviews -- the problem appears to be that no subviews are added and can therefore not disappear:

```
    -(IBAction)showNextText
{


    screenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self screenshot]];

    [screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [screenShotScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    [self.view addSubview:screenShotScrollView];
    [screenShotScrollView addSubview:screenShotView];
    screenShotScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;


    [self setUpNextText];
    [self removeOldText];

}

-(void)setUpNextText
{
    NSString* secondText = @"This is the second text shown if the user clicks next.";
    textView.text = secondText;
    textView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

-(IBAction)removeOldText{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5];

    [screenShotScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: The transition you need is something like in the old star wars movies? The position and size of the two screens don't change just the one overlaps the other at certain line and hides the other over time. Right?

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Exactly! I should have thought about star wars. It's like a line or curtain that you move to the left. The screens don't move - just what is revealed about the screens change. From 100% to 0% for the one above and 0% to 100% for the one below.

Comment: I have doubts that this kind of transition can be created easily! However I'll have a look at it tomorrow. You should consider some easy alpha blending animation: looks nice and is created within minutes.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Thanks a lot. I know alpha blending looks nice, but as I want to have a page-turn effect, I need this kind of transition. I tried it with UIScrollView as suggested by Codo, but no luck so far. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @n.evermind Have you actually tried `UIView transitionFromView ... ` and UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft? Or the UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp? Do look nice too :)

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Yes I know, but I need a horizontal curl up effect. Like the one in iBooks. I do it with shadows and it looks rather good. And it does work with one UITextView, but not with more (i.e. a textview, textfield etc.). It's a pain that Apple does not simple make their private API accessible to all... and introduce something like a TransitionCurlRightToLeft etc. Oh well, that's life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to question**

It's actually very simple: I've made a sample app to get the star wars(just calling it here) transition working. For simplicity I'll just call the two views firstView and secondView. firstView is shown (would be your screenshot) and secondView will slide in from the left. I've put a button on each view to animate the transition, which is wirde to `doTransition`. The important part is to set the sliding in view's properties `clipsToBounds = YES` and `autoresizesSubviews = NO`. That's it. I'll post some screenshots.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 480);
    secondView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    secondView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:firstView];   
    [self.view addSubview:secondView];  
}

- (IBAction)doTransition
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                     animations:^{
                         self.secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 
                                                            0, 
                                                            320, 
                                                            480);
                     }];
}
```

[image]
[image]

**Research on page curl**

I did some research on the page turn / curl effect. Mainly this is all present in iOS, with little effort you can create the iBook page turn effect, but it's accessing private methods and classes. I still encourage anyone to have a look at it, cause it might some day be opened.

- [Apple's iBooks Dynamic Page Curl](http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html) - Demo App by Steven Troughton-Smith
- [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) - An App with a custom page curl by Tom Brow, tried, compiled and looks nice!
- [App Store-safe Page Curl animations](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/) - Article on Tom Brow's Leaves App which has been branched ([twoPages](https://github.com/ole/leaves/tree/twopages)) by the author Ole Begemann
- [Implementing iBooks page curling using a conical deformation algorithm](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html)  - With a MacOS Demo App, very professional and advanced, though not an option for a quick shot still inspiring. Download the App!
- [The anatomy of a page curl](http://blog.flirble.org/2010/10/08/the-anatomy-of-a-page-curl/) - Mathematical approach

Comment: Thanks Nick, but again, I think this is not really what I was trying to do (my fault, I should have made it a bit clearer). Codo made a suggestion in terms of how to CLIP the screenshot, but it still won't work.

Comment: Changed the whole answer, well it's not the answer to your question but may still be interesting.

Comment: Thanks Nick, very kind of you. A lot I can look at. Also Hoha (above) provided some kind of solution which I need to test.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to put your upper view into a *UIScrollView*. Then you set the content size to be the same as the size of the *UIScrollView* and disable scrolling.

Next you do your original animation (*setFrame*) on the *UIScrollView*.

Basically, you then use the UIScrollView to introduce a separate coordinate system for the inner view. When the outer view (the scroll view) is made smaller, it will not distort the inner view, but clip it.

Comment: sounds right, but I tried to implement this (see code above), but it simply doesn't work. I guess I'm doing something wrong when trying to add all these different views. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "simply doesn't work" means? I can see two potential problems in your code: According to the screenshots, the views aren't supposed to be 480 pixel in height, but approximately 200 pixels. You should set the contentSize property of the scroll view.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that there is no animation at all anymore (no squeezing) and that the blue view (originally in the background) simply appears and the other white view (originally in the front) simply vanishes. About the pixel heights, I've set them to 200 so that I can see the button. About the contentSize property - how do I set this and why is this necessary? Sorry to be such a pain and thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect fillRect = self.view.bounds;

leftImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
leftImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
leftImageView.frame = fillRect;

rightImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
rightImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopRight;
rightImageView.frame = CGRectMake(fillRect.size.width, 0, 0, fillRect.size.height);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3];

leftImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, fillRect.size.height);
rightImageView.frame = fillRect;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't animate the `frame` but the `center`. See the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center).

Also, if you only need iOS 4 compatibility, use `-animateWithDuration:animations:`

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10
                 animations:^{ screenShotView.center = CGPointMake(x, y) } ];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do I do that? `[screenShotView setCenter:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 480)];` ?

Comment: `center` is a CGPoint with only two coordinates; use `CGPointMake(x, y)`

Comment: You could also animate the x part of the frame and keep the width and height the same: like `CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)`.

Comment: @n.evermind OK, maybe I'm misunderstanding you. What do you mean by "become less and less"?

Comment: @fabian798: I updated my question with a picture of how I would like it to appear. You suggested moving the whole thing out of view.

Comment: I see. My solution is wrong then. I thought you wanted to move it to the left.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would simply move the view to the left. I think I was rubbish at formulating my question -- I updated it with another image which illustrates what I would like to achieve.

Comment: @fabian789: Well, moving the thing out to the left is rather straight forward. I guess the problem is that I would like to alter the frame of the UIImage and that it doesn't really MASK the image, but distorts it. If you did the same with an UITextView, the UITextView wouldn't become distorted. Perhaps I need to nest the View into another View and then reduce the frame of that view in which I nested the other view...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand how you want your view to disappear.

If it's supposed to become more and more transparent, use the following code (instead of *setFrame*):

```
[screenShotView setAlpha: 0.0f];
```

If it's supposed to become smaller and smaller (but keep its center), then try:

```
[screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(screenShotView.frame.x, screenShotView.frame,y, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think this is not really what I need. I think I have not expressed myself very clearly -- I updated my post with an image which illustrates what I would like to achieve. If you could have a quick look, I'd be very grateful.